# Sender-Receiver with Razor MVC3

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to build a Sender-Receiver with two PartialViews for each and connect them by a send method in the Controller. The Ajax Action call requires the Id of the div, that has to be rerendered. But I want the sender to be entirely decoupled from the receiver.

Can I rerender a PartialView without the use of AjaxOptions.UpdateTargetId (for example in the Controller itself)?

The idea would be to allow multiple receivers to connect to one sender (similar to WebParts mechanism).

The Index View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test Ground";
    var sender = (MVCPortalViewModel.Models.SenderModel)ViewBag.Model.PortletModels["Sender"];
    var receiver = (MVCPortalViewModel.Models.ReceiverModel)ViewBag.Model.PortletModels["Receiver"];
}
<p>@Html.Partial("SenderPartView", sender)</p>
<p>@Html.Partial("ReceiverPartView", receiver)</p>
```

Sender View:

```
@model MVCPortalViewModel.Models.SenderModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ApplyColor", "Test", new { Color = @Model.Color }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = @ViewBag.SenderDivId, HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    <div id="senderPartDiv" style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <div style="background-color: @Model.Color">
            <h2>@Model.Title</h2>
        </div>
            <p>Hallo @Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name</p>
            <p>
                @Html.Editor("Color")
                <input type="submit" value="Apply Color" />
            </p>
            <p>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Send Color", "SendColor", new { Color = @Model.Color }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = @ViewBag.ReceiverDivId, HttpMethod = "Post" })
            </p>
    </div>
}
```

Receiver View:

```
@model MVCPortalViewModel.Models.ReceiverModel

<div id="receiverPartDiv" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <h2 style="background-color: @Model.Color">@Model.Title</h2> 
    <p>Color: @Model.Color</p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Model = Model;
        ViewBag.ReceiverDivId = "receiverPartDiv";
        ViewBag.SenderDivId = "senderPartDiv";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SendColor(string Color)
    {
        var receiverModel = ((ReceiverModel)Model.PortletModels["Receiver"]);
        receiverModel.Color = Color;

        ViewBag.ReceiverDivId = "receiverPartDiv";
        ViewBag.SenderDivId = "senderPartDiv";

        return PartialView("ReceiverPartView", receiverModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: the more I think about this problem the more I have the feeling you should implement a JavaScript solution. It doesn't make sense to go back to the server just to update a local view, unless you have other responsibilities on the server.

Comment: this is just an abstract example, there probably will be more responsibilities on the server in the sender-receiver solution I need (as loading more data from the server for example).
I would also prefer a server version because it is unit testable.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from clientside JQuery approaches I came up with a solution using RenderAction and a separate Controller for the receivers.

Index View:

```
@model MVCPortalViewModel.Models.SenderModel
<p>@Html.Partial("Sender", Model)</p>
<p>
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Receive1", "Receiver", Model); }
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Receive2", "Receiver", Model); }
</p>
```

Sender PartialView:

```
@model MVCPortalViewModel.Models.SenderModel
@using (@Html.BeginForm(new { Color = @Model.Color }))
{
    <h2 style="background-color: @Model.Color;">@Model.Title</h2>
    <p>
        Send Color: 
        @Html.Editor("Color")
        <input type="submit" value="Send Color" id="sendButton" />
    </p>
}
```

Receiver PartialView:

```
@model MVCPortalViewModel.Models.ReceiverModel
<h2 style="background-color: @Model.Color">@Model.Title</h2>
<p>
    Color: 
    @Html.Display("Color")
</p>
```

Controller:

```
public class ChildActionController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string Color)
        {
            SenderModel sender = new SenderModel { Title = "Sender", Color = "red" };
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Color))
            {
                sender.Color = Color;
            }
            return View(sender);
        }
}
```

Receiver Controller for Connection:

```
public class ReceiverController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Receive1(SenderModel Sender)
        {
            ReceiverModel receiver = new ReceiverModel { Title = "Receiver1" };
            receiver.Color = Sender.Color;
            return PartialView("MessageReceiver", receiver);
        }
        public ActionResult Receive1(SenderModel Sender) { ... }
}
```